# AngularJS - resolve $http instead injecting value

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-http

I have a [small tool](http://diablobulgaria.org/tools/community-bg/), using AngularJS with the `.value()` recipe, which currently dumps almost the entire DB as JSON into this value. So I want to optimise the pages by loading some of this information on demand with $http  before changing the view.

**index.php** (ugly)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.value('MembersListData', <?php echo $MembersListDB; ?>);
        app.value('ChartsData', <?php echo $MembersChartsDB; ?>);
    </script>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('CommunityInfo', ['ngRoute', 'chart.js'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
        $routeProvider
            // main page (listing)
            .when('/members', {
                controller: 'MembersController',
                templateUrl: self.location.pathname + '/views/members-list.html'
            })
            // member of the list (load additional data from request.php)
            .when('/member/:memberID', {
                controller: 'MembersController',
                // ----- new code (start) -----
                resolve: {
                    MemberDataDB: function($http, $route){
                        return $http.
                            get(
                                self.location.origin +
                                self.location.pathname +
                                'request.php?rop=info&battleTag=' +
                                $route.current.params.memberID
                            )
                            .then(
                                function(response){
                                    return response.data;
                                }
                            )
                    }
                },
                // ----- new code (end) -----
                templateUrl: self.location.pathname + '/views/member-data.html'
            })
    })


    .factory('MembersFactory', function($http, MembersListData, ChartsData){
        // factory functions & initialization
    })


    .controller('MembersController', 
    function($scope, $routeParams, $location, MembersFactory, MemberDataDB){
        function init(){

            // other initialization

            if (memberID){
                // copy part of the current data
                $scope.memberData = $scope.membersList[memberID];
                if (!$scope.memberData){
                    // member not found - redirect to list
                    $location.path('/members');
                }
                // add the new data
                angular.merge($scope.memberData, MemberDataDB); // new code
            }
        }
        init();
    });
```

This change is working fine on member page, but loading the list (main page) throws injector error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=MemberDataDBProvider%20%3C-%20MemberDataDB%20%3C-%20MembersController

But none of the cases seems to apply here

- Service (factory) is defined
- Module is defined once
- There is only one controller
- Using $scope only in the controller (not entirely sure)

Am I on the right track? Is there other/better (and beautiful) way to do this?

Comment: too messy, can you transfer it in a service,

Answer (score 2):

The error is being thrown because in the main route, you haven't defined the  `MemberDataDB` resolve variable, although you're sharing the controller between your routes. Therefore, `MembersController` doesn't know what `MemberDataDB` is, when it is in the `/members` route. Try this:

```
 .when('/members', {
            controller: 'MembersController',
            templateUrl: self.location.pathname + '/views/members-list.html',
            resolve: {
              MemberDataDB: function() {return {}};
            }
        })
```

Comment: It works only if `MemberDataDB` is a function with return.

Comment: RIght you are. I'll make the correction. Was in a hurry!

Comment: Tested some more and `MemberDataDB` could just be a function without return, e.g. `MemberDataDB: function() {}`. @nikjohn you still have messed up syntax in the code ( `function() {return }` and `function() {return {}}` are ok, but `function() return {}` is not.